# too many re-renders. when trying to update an object in array state

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, setstate

I'm trying to code To do list. I have an array that includes all the tasks as an objects.
every task has an property called "checked" to indicate me if one has checked this task.
When a task got checked, i have onClicked function that changes the "checked" property of the specified task in the array, and in this point I have an error of "too many re-renders".
whould like your help..

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import react from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function ToDoList() {
  const [allTasks, setAllTasks] = useState([]);
  const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState({ value: "" });
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleChanged = ({ target }) => {
    setNewTask({
      value: target.value,
      id: currentIndex,
      checked: false
    });
  };

  function onClicked() {
    if (newTask.value === "") return;
    setAllTasks((prev) => {
      return [newTask, ...prev];
    });
    setNewTask({ value: "" });
    setCurrentIndex((prevCurrentIndex) => prevCurrentIndex + 1);
  }

  const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      onClicked();
    }
  };

  const onCheck = (i) => {
    const task = { ...allTasks[i] };
    task.checked = !task.checked;

    const taskState = [...allTasks];
    taskState[i] = task;

    setAllTasks(taskState);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        <u>
          <b>To Do List</b>
        </u>
      </h1>
      <input
        value={newTask.value}
        onChange={handleChanged}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
      />
      <button onClick={onClicked} />
      <h1>{newTask.value}</h1>
      <lo>
        {allTasks.map((item, i) => (
          <li>
            {item.checked ? (
              <input type="checkbox" checked={true} onClick={onCheck(i)} />
            ) : (
              <input type="checkbox" checked={false} onClick={onCheck(i)} />
            )}

            {item.value}
          </li>
        ))}
      </lo>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Immediately upon render you call the `onCheck` function (using the *result* of the function, which is `undefined`, as the actual click handler):

```
onClick={onCheck(i)}
```

Which updates state, which triggers a re-render, which calls the function, which updates state, etc., etc.

Don't call `onCheck` immediately during the render.  Call it when the user clicks on the element by wrapping it in a function:

```
onClick={() => onCheck(i)}
```

This sets the function itself as the click handler and only invokes that function when that even occurs.

Comment: Thank u. its works good. But I dont understand why. Why if I write onClick={onCheck(i)} it call the function automatically? it's not depend on a click?

Comment: @asafH: Because in JavaScript adding parentheses after a function reference *calls the function*.  So `onCheck` is the function reference, `onCheck()` *calls* the function.  If you didn't need to pass a specific value to the function then you could just use the reference directly: `onClick={onCheck}`.  But since you do need to pass a specific value then in this case what you do is call the function from within another function, and just pass *that* function reference to the `onClick` attribute.  In this case a single-statement anonymous arrow function.

Comment: thank u man! good explanation.